# I get "error RA0000" error while registering DocMergeConnector.dll

Tags: windows

I want to Register a dll file and I run the following command

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Regasm.exe /tlb/codebase "C:\Program Files\Nuance\eCopy PDF Pro Office 6\bin\Connectors\DocMerge\DocMergeConnector.dll"
```

But I get the following error:-

> RegAsm : error RA0000 : Unknown option: /tlb/codebase

can you help?

Answer (score 1):

You are using incorrect syntax. 
From the [regasm help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) I see that there are two options `/tlb` and `/codebase`.

Try putting a space in between.